# Return the count within a column where there are no matches

Tags: sqlite

I have these two tables.

**dispatch**

```
CREATE TABLE dispatch (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    FDID INTEGER,
    COUNTYNUM TEXT,
    TRANS1 TEXT
);
```

With this data ...

```
INSERT INTO "dispatch" ("ID","FDID","COUNTYNUM","TRANS1") VALUES ('470638','28','201612310026','2016-12-31T00:26:41.123-05:00');
INSERT INTO "dispatch" ("ID","FDID","COUNTYNUM","TRANS1") VALUES ('470640','26','201612310031','2016-12-31T00:31:34.747-05:00');
INSERT INTO "dispatch" ("ID","FDID","COUNTYNUM","TRANS1") VALUES ('470670','26','201612311136','2016-12-31T11:36:33.323-05:00');
INSERT INTO "dispatch" ("ID","FDID","COUNTYNUM","TRANS1") VALUES ('470688','26','201612311332','2016-12-31T13:32:09.940-05:00');
INSERT INTO "dispatch" ("ID","FDID","COUNTYNUM","TRANS1") VALUES ('470719','26','201612311929','2016-12-31T19:29:23.487-05:00');
INSERT INTO "dispatch" ("ID","FDID","COUNTYNUM","TRANS1") VALUES ('470749','28','201612312301','2016-12-31T23:02:06.607-05:00');
INSERT INTO "dispatch" ("ID","FDID","COUNTYNUM","TRANS1") VALUES ('470769','26','201701010033','2017-01-01T00:33:46.750-05:00');
INSERT INTO "dispatch" ("ID","FDID","COUNTYNUM","TRANS1") VALUES ('470849','28','201701012101','2017-01-01T21:01:38.073-05:00');
INSERT INTO "dispatch" ("ID","FDID","COUNTYNUM","TRANS1") VALUES ('470880','28','201701020640','2017-01-02T06:41:10.087-05:00');
INSERT INTO "dispatch" ("ID","FDID","COUNTYNUM","TRANS1") VALUES ('470893','28','201701021110','2017-01-02T11:10:28.280-05:00');
INSERT INTO "dispatch" ("ID","FDID","COUNTYNUM","TRANS1") VALUES ('470912','28','201701021333','2017-01-02T13:33:31.247-05:00');
INSERT INTO "dispatch" ("ID","FDID","COUNTYNUM","TRANS1") VALUES ('470915','26','201701021350','2017-01-02T13:50:48.440-05:00');
INSERT INTO "dispatch" ("ID","FDID","COUNTYNUM","TRANS1") VALUES ('470918','28','201701021416','2017-01-02T14:16:37.833-05:00');
INSERT INTO "dispatch" ("ID","FDID","COUNTYNUM","TRANS1") VALUES ('470935','26','201701021546','2017-01-02T15:46:07.347-05:00');
INSERT INTO "dispatch" ("ID","FDID","COUNTYNUM","TRANS1") VALUES ('470960','28','201701022009','2017-01-02T20:09:33.177-05:00');
```

**points**

```
CREATE TABLE points (
    rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    powId INTEGER,
    userId INTEGER,
    timeStart DATETIME,
    timeEnd DATETIME,
    points NUMERIC,
    COUNTYNUM NUMERIC,
--  FOREIGN KEY(powId) REFERENCES points_power(powId)
--  FOREIGN KEY(userId) REFERENCES users(userId)
    UNIQUE(userId, timeStart, COUNTYNUM) ON CONFLICT IGNORE
);
```

With this data ...

```
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('1','7','2','2016-12-31T19:29:23-0500','2016-12-31T20:29:23-0500','2','201612311929');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('2','7','4','2016-12-31T19:29:23-0500','2016-12-31T20:29:23-0500','2','201612311929');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('3','7','12','2016-12-31T19:29:23-0500','2016-12-31T20:29:23-0500','2','201612311929');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('4','7','16','2016-12-31T19:29:23-0500','2016-12-31T20:29:23-0500','2','201612311929');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('5','7','585','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('6','7','2','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('7','7','12','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('9','7','11','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('10','7','593','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('11','7','14','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('12','7','13','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('13','7','11','2017-01-02T13:50:48-0500','2017-01-02T14:50:48-0500','2','201701021350');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('14','7','16','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('15','7','16','2017-01-01T00:33:46-0500','2017-01-01T01:33:46-0500','2','201701010033');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('16','7','2','2017-01-02T13:50:48-0500','2017-01-02T14:50:48-0500','2','201701021350');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('17','13','1','2017-01-02T17:00:00-0500','2017-01-02T21:00:00-0500','1',NULL);
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('18','13','2','2017-01-02T17:00:00-0500','2017-01-02T21:00:00-0500','1',NULL);
```

I'm trying to generate a report based on these two tables. So I used this query, but it's not quite giving me the output that I want.

```
SELECT strftime('%Y', TRANS1) AS Year, strftime('%m', TRANS1) AS Month, COUNT(*) AS Incidents, (SELECT COUNT(COUNTYNUM) FROM points WHERE dispatch.COUNTYNUM = points.COUNTYNUM) AS Zero FROM dispatch WHERE FDID = 26 GROUP BY Year, Month;
```

I'm getting ...

```
Year  Month  Incidents  Zero
2016  12     3          0
2017  01     4          8
```

When I do this query ...

```
SELECT ID, FDID, COUNTYNUM, TRANS1, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM points WHERE points.COUNTYNUM = dispatch.COUNTYNUM) AS Zero FROM dispatch WHERE FDID = 26 AND Zero = 0;
```

I get correct results ...

```
ID      FDID  COUNTYNUM     TRANS1                         Zero
470640  26    201612310031  2016-12-31T00:31:34.747-05:00  0
470670  26    201612311136  2016-12-31T11:36:33.323-05:00  0
470688  26    201612311332  2016-12-31T13:32:09.940-05:00  0
```

That's correct, but it means the previous query should have returned this table.

```
Year  Month  Incidents  Zero
2016  12     4          1
2017  01     3          0
```

Because `COUNTYNUM` `201612311929` was not in the result set.

I'm not sure if I'm making any sense of this right now. Rubby ducky debugging into this box has actually got me more confused. Mostly because the example data set that I gave produces different results than my actual production dataset. This if anyone has ANY idea on what I'm trying to do, I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

These are the relevant parts of your query:

```
SELECT ...,
       (SELECT ... WHERE ... = dispatch.COUNTYNUM)
FROM dispatch
GROUP BY Year, Month;
```

The correlated subquery refers to the `COUNTYNUM` column, but this is not one of those columns by which the table is grouped. This means that for each result row, there are multiple possible `COUNTYNUM` values in the group. Which one you get is random. (This is for compatibility with MySQL; other databases report an error.)